# SSRS Reports while I select CSV format rendering it gives error

Tags: csv, reporting-services, report

I migrated SSRS Reports from 2008 to 2019. All reports works Good with respect to .CSV file and other formats. However there is one report where .CSV selection is shown for selection.

**Note:** In Tablix, properties I set the DataElementOutput = 'Output'

When I select .CSV it displays the following error:

### Reporting Services Error

Error: Subreport could not be shown. (rrRenderingError)
Error: Subreport could not be shown.

---

SQL Server Reporting Services

---

It will be Great if you let me know how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The uploaded image was missing, so please upload it again

Comment: Upload image contains the error message, that error messaged is added in the question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: SSRS Report is created in Visual studio, and the report is loaded in Report Server. While selecting .xlsx, .pdf and other formats the report is provided in that format. However, when .csv is selected it gives error. No specific code is added in the report.